# AngularJS SPA needs to reload to recognize the jwt token in localstorage

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sails.js, jwt

everything good ?

Today I need your help to solve a token authentication problem (jwt) in my SPA AngularJS application (I use NodeJS in the backend).

When I log in, the credentials are validated in the backend and if I succeed I get a token that is stored in localstorage.

But when I start making my requests to the protected endpoints it is not possible to access, enough to both have to reload the page, which is a tragedy for my SPA AngularJS application.

I have two more verification methods that I use to check the token:

isLoggedIn: that verifies that the token has not been issued.

currentUser: which takes the user data in the payload of the token.

These two methods are called by the navbar controller which updates the links and the user name of the navbar.

One final note is: I have a method: logout, which excludes the token, but even after deleting I have to reload the page, otherwise I can still make requests to protected endpoinds, and having to reload my SPA is a tragedy.

I hope I have given you all the details about the problem,

Best regards

Comment: I have found that the problem is in the request made with $ resource, when I use $ http it works fine, but I need to use the $ resource because I am working on Restful api. So briefly summarizing what the problem is in the way I'm passing the jwt headers in $ resource. but then what would be the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I was using the $ resource of angularjs and passing the token as an object in the headers as below, calling the method of calling the token of the localstorage directly on the object.

```
return $resource('user/:userId', null, {

      'update': {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AuthService.getToken();
        }
      };
```

So I changed, created a variable token and called the method of calling the token, and then passed the variable token to the headers in the object.

```
var token = AuthService.getToken();

    return $resource('user/:userId', null, {

      'update': {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want that after login token should be go with every request without refreshing your application then you have to create a Interceptor or a service where you set your token in options and it'll go with your every request.

[You can refer to this article and let me know further if any query (Click me!).](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

2. Make sure on clicking logout

   localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', JSON.stringify(false));
   this.currentUser("");

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your auth flow is but you need a http-service that will either get or post the token based on the current state.

Something like

```
  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs, silent: boolean = false): Observable<Response> {
  let getStream = () => {
    return Observable.from([true])
      .flatMap((_) => {
        if (!silent) this.beginActivity();
        return this.authHttp.get(url, this.prepareOptionsForJsonApi(options));
      })
      .catch((res) => { return this.handleError(res); })
      .do(noop,
      (error) => { this.publishError(error); },
      () => { if (!silent) this.endActivity(); });
  };

  return this.whenTokenReady(getStream);
}

  post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  let postStream = () => {
    return Observable.from([true])
      .flatMap((_) => {
        this.beginActivity();
        return this.authHttp.post(url, body, this.prepareOptionsForJsonApi(options));
      })
      .catch((res) => { return this.handleError(res); })
      .do(noop,
      (error) => { this.publishError(error); },
      () => { this.endActivity(); });
  };

  return this.whenTokenReady(postStream);
}
```